# Header background Clip off due to Horizontal Scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, css

I am working on a page for iPad and iPhone wherein I have a header with buttons on the leftmost and rightmost corners and the content lies below the header.

The CSS of the header has already been done such that the width of the header changes with the orienation of ipad, iPhone displaying all the buttons on the left and right of the header.

But when my content exceeds a certain width, a horizontal scroll appears and the header gets clipped off when I scroll to the rightmost data of the page.

A sample of the problem I face can be viewed in this URL:

http://www.kalee-eversole.com/

Replica of the problem:

http://www.tempestblog.com/2011/06/19/common-css-problem-header-background-cut-off-when-page-scrolled-horizontally/

Is there any workaround for this problem? Any valuable suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the `header` tag that is getting clipped off but the `body`, where you have an image (simulating the header) as background.

The problem seems to be that the your `body` has a width of `100%` (browser width) while the header has `1024px` width (plus child elements negative margins), so when the browser is smaller than 1024 the body only spans up to the browser width, leaving the extra scroll area with no background image.

Try adding this to the CSS of your **body** tag:

```
min-width:1192px;
```

*(1024 from the header width + 98 + 70 from the header inner elements left and right negative margins)*